# How to set image before pushing to destination view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to show image on the profile button of my destination view controller but when I am trying to assign image from my source view controller it is crashing as my "proficPicButton" is nil.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FacebookTableViewCell
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let objFriendsDetailViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsDetailViewController") as! FriendsDetailViewController
    objFriendsDetailViewController.friendsName = cell.friendsName.text! //Can Assign Data to the property "friendsName"
    objFriendsDetailViewController.remindersDataDict = ["birthDay":cell.friendsBirthDay.text!] //Can Assign Data to the property "remindersDataDict"

    let image = cell.profilePicButton.image(for: .normal)

    print(objFriendsDetailViewController)
    print(objFriendsDetailViewController.remindersTableView) //It says nil
    print(objFriendsDetailViewController.profilePicButton) //It says nil

    objFriendsDetailViewController.profilePicButton.setImage(image, for: .normal) //Can't Assign Image to the property "profilePicButton"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objFriendsDetailViewController, animated: true)
```

How can I set image from my source view controller to the button in the destination view controller?

Comment: Create a `UIImage` variable in your destination view controller, set it to the image you wish and change the view's image in the `viewDidLoad` function of your destination VC.

Answer (score 0):

The UI components of your destination view controller are **not set** at the moment your `push` is triggered. The actual place of the UI components is in **set** mode is the `viewDidLoad()` of your view controller. So, you are trying to set an image before the UI actually transitions from **not set** to **set** state. And your `Button` is implicitly unwrapped optional which tells, ***crash if accessed before initialized or if accessed while the value is nil***.

Now, this isn't the way to achieve what you're trying. The actual way of doing this is:

- Have a property on the destination view controller
- Pass the object to that property when you initialize the destination view controller
- When the destination view controller is ready (essentially, the `viewDidLoad()`) you can update the corresponding view with that property

Answer (score 0):

```
 let image = cell.profilePicButton.image(for: .normal)

print(objFriendsDetailViewController)
print(objFriendsDetailViewController.remindersTableView) //It says nil
print(objFriendsDetailViewController.profilePicButton) //It says nil
//These are nil because  Controller from storyboard does come into memory yet 

objFriendsDetailViewController.imageFromPreviousButton = image
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objFriendsDetailViewController, animated: true)
```

Rather you can do

```
   Class  FriendsDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageFromPreviousButton = UIImage()
    @IBOutlet var profilePicButton: UIButton!
     Override func viewDidLoad() {
       profilePicButton.setImage(imageFromPreviousButton, for: .normal)
     }
}
```